# Editing of file geodatabase

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

How can one edit file geodatabase in QGIS. I have tried with even version 3.0 of QGIS, but it can't still be done.

Comment: For editing geodatabase you must have QGIS and GDAL with this driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html. This driver is read only http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html.

Comment: Whats the process like please

Comment: @IYKE Are you talking about editing the feature classes in the file geodatabase or editing the schema of the file geodatabase?

Comment: It might help if you indicate your operating system and whether you installed QGIS via the osgeo4w setup or via a standalone installer.  If osgeo4W then you need to install the gdal-filegdb: OGR FileGDB driver in the libraries section.  I have both the "regular" and developer's version and can edit features in a GDB although I prefer to make shapefiles from them for that purpose.  I'm using QGIS 3.